# Sending Outlook email in VBA, any subject with a colon ":" causes the email to be sent blank

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a macro that copies a word document content, pastes it into an email. Then pulls email addresses and names from Excel, and sends each person the email with an attachment. (Essentially a mailmerge)

Problem is, anytime the subject has a colon ":", the email message sends as blank. This doesn't happen if I save the email, nor when I display it. Only happens if it is immediately sent.

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SendInitialEmail()
    'directory of email body
    Dim dirEmailBody As String

    ' Directory of email template
    dirEmailBody = _
        "C:\Users\me\Documents\Email Body.docx"

    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim docEmail As Document

    ' Opens email template and copies it
    Set wordApp = New Word.Application
    Set docEmail = wordApp.Documents.Open(dirEmailBody)
    docEmail.Content.Copy

    Dim outEdit As Document
    Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
    Set outApp = New Outlook.Application
    Dim outMail As MailItem

    ' The names/emails to send too
    Dim sendName As String, sendEmail As String, _
        ccEmail As String, siteName As String

    Dim row As Integer
    ' Was only testing on one row, but generally this pulls from 
    'a sheet of names and email addresses to send an email with attachments too.
    For row = 1 to 1

        sendName = actSheet.Cells(row, 1)
        sendEmail = actSheet.Cells(row, 2)
        ccEmail = actSheet.Cells(row, 3)
        siteName = actSheet.Cells(row, 4)

        Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With outMail
            .SendUsingAccount = outApp.Session.Accounts.Item(1)
            .To = "myemailaddress to test@gmail.com"
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .subject = _
                "Is the error cause of a colon: Email test to me" 
                ' it was

            Set outEdit = .GetInspector.WordEditor
            outEdit.Content.Paste
            outEdit.Range(0).InsertBefore ("Dear " & sendName & "," & vbNewLine)
            ' If I do display, it shows up correctly. 
            ' If I display then send it is fine (workaround)
            .Send
        End With
    Next row

        docEmail.Close
        wordApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following:

`Set outEdit = .GetInspector.WordEditor
    outEdit.Content.Paste
    outEdit.Range(0).InsertBefore ("Dear " & sendName & "," & vbNewLine)`

and add:

```
`.Body = "Dear " & sendName & "," & vbNewLine & docEmail.Content.Text`
```

The colon is not the problem.

Comment: That worked! What was the problem then? Also, how can I get the formatting back in?

Comment: Not 100% why it is breaking. When I explored the object for outEdit.content, Outlook would crash. So I explored the word document object and found that the .contents.text would worked. I also saw .formattedtext. I have not tried it yet. If I were you, I would create a breakpoint after 'Set docEmail = wordApp.Documents.Open(dirEmailBody)'. Run the code. Then when it stops, open the Locals Window in "View" menu. Expand the docEmail object and look for the attribute that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Chr() command, in this case the ":" is Chr(58)